# Trying to automate a website login with PowerShell(Yahoo)

Tags: powershell

I was trying to automate the login for Yahoo website using powershell.
The script is taking the username where as while entering password it is throwing an error.

**Script:**

```
Function OpenYahoo{
$username = "username"
$password = "Password"
$ie = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application; 
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.Navigate("https://www.in.yahoo.com");
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; 
}
$ie.Document.getElementById('ysignin').Click();
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; 
}
$email = $ie.Document.getElementById('login-username').value() = $username;
$ie.Document.getElementById('login-signin').Click();
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; 
} 
$pswd = $ie.Document.getElementById('login-passwd').value() = $password;
$ie.Document.getElementById('login-signin').Click();
}
OpenYahoo
```

**Error:**

Method invocation failed because [System.DBNull] does not contain a method named 'value'.
At C:\Users\hp\Desktop\test.ps1:22 char:9

- $pswd = $ie.Document.getElementById('login-passwd').value() = $passwo ...
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: probably the Dom element having the id **login-passwd** is not present. Maibe there is an additional  step/page  before landing on the one where you have to provide  the password.  A  Captcha step/page for example, can be displayed before you have to provide the password.

Comment: There is no captcha page appearing. It directly navigates to password page once entered the username.
Below is the DOM elements I got for password filed.
<input type="password" id="login-passwd" class="password" name="password" placeholder=" " autofocus="" autocomplete="current-password" data-rapid-tracking="true" data-ylk="elm:input;elmt:focus;slk:passwd;mKey:password-challenge-focus-passwd">

Comment: Sadly, Internet Explorer is going away.  It's the only web browser which supports COM.  Once it does, you'll have to make your code work in other browsers.  FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You're in for a really rough time if you're trying to use an IE ComObject in this day and age, it's going to have major compatibility problems with most websites.

I recommend going with a browser automation tool. There's a PowerShell specific module called [Monocle](https://github.com/Badgerati/Monocle), though you'll probably want to manually install the module by downloading the GitHub repo instead of using the Install-Module command - the version that's on powershellgallery.com hasn't received any of the new updates.

There's also a [Selenium module](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell) available.

Venturing outside of PowerShell, there's a whole host of [other browser automation tools](https://github.com/angrykoala/awesome-browser-automation) available.

I'm sorry this answer doesn't directly provide code that accomplishes what you're looking for, but I hope this was helpful nonetheless. If you do accomplish what you want, please be sure to post an answer to your own question here so that it helps others.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable piece of information.
I will surely post the answer once I will get the desired result.